# Error in function createFiberFromTypeAndProps in ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25058

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am learning to create a gatsby blog website with a YouTube tutorial. I have followed the exact steps as shown in the tutorials. There were errors that were related to graphql query format. which were solved.

I have searched for the error. But all the answers were related to react app. There was no answers related to gatsby. So I was unable to figure out the right way to solve it.

The page loads at local server port 8000. The error comes while clicking the `Read more` button to see the single post. The error seems to be of React.

Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `singlePost`.

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-starter-hello-world-m685p

singlePost.js

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import { H1 } from "../elements"
import { Container, Post, FeatureImage, Seo } from "../components"

const singlePost = ({ data }) => {
  const featureImage = data.mdx.frontmatter.featureImage.childImageSharp.fixed

  const seoImage = data.mdx.frontmatter.featureImage.publicURL

  return (
    <Container>
      <Seo
        title={data.mdx.frontmatter.title}
        image={seoImage}
        description={data.mdx.frontmatter.excerpt}
      />
      <FeatureImage fixed={featureImage} />
      <Post>
        <H1 margin="0 0 2rem 0">{data.mdx.frontmatter.title}</H1>
        <MDXRenderer>{data.mdx.body}</MDXRenderer>
      </Post>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default singlePost

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query SinglePostQuery($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        date
        excerpt
        slug
        title
        featureImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your component must be named `SinglePost` instead of `singlePost` (notice the capitalization), so:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import { H1 } from "../elements"
import { Container, Post, FeatureImage, Seo } from "../components"

const SinglePost = ({ data }) => {
  const featureImage = data.mdx.frontmatter.featureImage.childImageSharp.fixed

  const seoImage = data.mdx.frontmatter.featureImage.publicURL

  return (
    <Container>
      <Seo
        title={data.mdx.frontmatter.title}
        image={seoImage}
        description={data.mdx.frontmatter.excerpt}
      />
      <FeatureImage fixed={featureImage} />
      <Post>
        <H1 margin="0 0 2rem 0">{data.mdx.frontmatter.title}</H1>
        <MDXRenderer>{data.mdx.body}</MDXRenderer>
      </Post>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default singlePost

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query SinglePostQuery($id: String!) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        date
        excerpt
        slug
        title
        featureImage {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

All React component names must start with a capital letter. Otherwise, it will be treated as a built-in element like a `<div>` or a `<span>` (or another HTML tag). In JSX, rendering a component that begins with a lowercase letter compiles down to React.

---

Outside the scope of the question, check the importation/exportation of the components and it's naming, because this kind of issue is usually related to that (for future scenarios/issues). If a component is exported as default, it must be imported like:

```
import DefaultComponent from '../path/to/default/component'
```

Otherwise, it needs to be imported as:

```
import { NonDefaultComponent} from '../path/to/non-default/component'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did try to capitalize the component but did not work. But it did help me to reanalyze the components in this file. And the problem was I had misspelled the component name in the component file. Now, it is resolved.